# How to use roboeletric in Android Studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric with AndroidStudio and Gradle but no success.
Someone has achieved this?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are still using maven and decided to migrate before christmas.
But you can follow Square guys: https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin